# Как сделать переходы (кнопки) в разные части сайта?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

Я знаю, что это очень тупой вопрос, прошу не бить (месяц обучения).
Опишу вопрос поточнее. Как сделать переходы между разными частями сайта в виде кнопок? Я имею ввиду, например, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку "главное" пользователь переходил на главную страницу, а при нажатии условной кнопки "товары" он попадал на страницу с товарами (при этом меняется путь к странице).
Я думаю, вы поняли, что я имею ввиду, это реализовано на большинстве сайтов. Что вообще для этого нужно, как это делать? Может быть есть какая-нибудь статья или гайд? Буду рад любому объяснению и помощи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тег HTML "a" в помощь

http://htmlbook.ru/html/a

Answer (score 0):

Сделать можно с помощью id элемента и якорной ссылки:

```html
<div id="foobar">...</div>
<p><a href="#foobar">Перейти к элементу с ID "foobar" </a></p>
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Это называется якорное меню. В теге a в атрибуте href указываешь идентификатор и при клике на эту ссылку ты перейдешь на элемент (часть страницы) с таким же идентификатором.